# Как из словаря взять нужное?

Tags: python

У меня есть код:

```
def main():
    ip = str(input("ip: "))
    time = str(input("time (max 250): "))
    port = str(input("port: "))
    method = str(input("method (CLDAP, NTP, DNS): "))
    return ip, time, port, method

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(main())
```

Он возвращает `('1284', '250', '234', 'DNS')`.

Как мне отделить элементы, то есть, сделать как-то так:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   ip = main().ip
   time = main().time
   port = main().port
   method = main().method
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция main возвращает кортеж из 4 элементов: ip, time, port, method.
Чтобы этим значениям присвоить собственную переменную, нужно добавить при вызове main следующее:

```
    ip, time, port, method = main()
```

В итоге получим:

```
def main():
    ip = str(input("ip: "))
    time = str(input("time (max 250): "))
    port = str(input("port: "))
    method = str(input("method (CLDAP, NTP, DNS): "))
    return ip, time, port, method

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ip, time, port, method = main()
    print(ip, time, port, method)
```

Comment: спасибо!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде не увидел словаря. Но если нужно реализовать возможность доступа к аргументам через точку, то самые очевидные варианты - это создать класс или использовать именованный кортеж:

```
class Mane:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ip = str(input("ip: "))
        self.time = str(input("time (max 250): "))
        self.port = str(input("port: "))
        self.method = str(input("method (CLDAP, NTP, DNS): "))
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)

main = Mane()
'''
ip: 1.1.1.176
time (max 250): 100
port: 2000
method (CLDAP, NTP, DNS): DNS
'''
print(main)
'''
{'ip': '1.1.1.176', 'time': '100', 'port': '2000', 'method': 'DNS'}
'''
main.ip
'''
'1.1.1.176'
```

```
from collections import namedtuple

ip = str(input("ip: "))
time = str(input("time (max 250): "))
port = str(input("port: "))
method = str(input("method (CLDAP, NTP, DNS): "))

Main = namedtuple('Main', 'ip time port method')
main = Main(ip, time, port, method)

print(main)
'''
Main(ip='1.1.1.176', time='200', port='2000', method='DNS')
'''
main.ip
'''
'1.1.1.176'
```

Правда, в случае именованного кортежа объект будет неизменяемый.